# Angular js + jquery qtip and Jasmine Test case

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine

I have one directive which shows qtip tooltip on hover of the element.I want to write jasmine test case for the directive.But I am unable to find qtip div in html.

My code is

```
var testModule = require('../Test.js');

testModule.directive('headerTooltip',['$compile','$filter', function($compile,$filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link : function(scope, element) {

            var template =  '<a id="tooltip">Test1</a>';
            element.html('').append( $compile( template )( scope ) );
            var qTipContent = '<div class="qTipContent" style="display: none;">'+
                '<h4>Hello</h4><div class="query content">Test tooltip on hover</div></div>';

            angular.element('#tooltip').qtip({
                id:'data-tooltip',
                overwrite:false,

                content: $compile(qTipContent)(scope),
                hide: { fixed: true, delay: 250 },
                style: { tip:{corner: true, width:22, height:12 }, padding: 10, border: { radius: 5, width: 3 }, width: 340,classes:'tooltip-qtip-data' },
                position: {  my:'bottom center', at:'top center' },
                show: { when: { event: 'mouseover'} }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

My Test case is written like

```
beforeEach(module('myModule'));

describe('headerTooltip Directive', function () {
    var element,scope,$compile,$document;
    beforeEach( inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope,_$document_) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $document = _$document_;
    }));

    it('should show tooltip on hover of header', function () {

    element = angular.element('<header-tooltip> </header-tooltip>');
    var template = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(template.find('a').length).toBe(1);
    expect(template.find('a').text().trim()).toBe('test1');
    template.find('a').trigger('mouseover');
    expect($document.find('body').find('#qtip-data-tooltip')).toBeDefined();
    expect($document.find('body').find('#qtip-data-tooltip').length).toBe(1);
    });

});
```

But the last expect with length is getting failed.
I had tried with angular.element but it's not working also.
I have checked and the qtip content data is generated in body tag directly.

Does anyone face this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Comment: ever found an answer to this?